# TRUE if at least one condition true in php

Tags: php

I am trying echo result "OK" if one of variable condition true either both true

```
<div class="box-title">
<?php
$point = $_SESSION['myPoints']; 
$user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$flag = "select m_boost from users where id = $user_id ";
// FOR EXAMPLE
$point = 2000;
$flag = 1;
// condition start
if(($point < '1000') || ($flag == '0') ){
echo "<h4>Not OK</h4>";
} else { ?>
echo "<h4>OK</h4>";
<?php }?>
</div>
```

it's working if i do like this

```
if(($point == '1000') || ($flag == '0') ){
```

---

but i want to pass this statement

```
if(($point < '1000') || ($flag == '0') ){
```

Comment: in your example both conditions are false: 1000 is not smaller than 1000 and 1 is not (even without typesafety) equal to 0. Are you looking for the `<=` operator? (smaller or equal). btw. you are comparing numbers to strings, which often works because PHP tries a lot of casting, but is not always save

Comment: Your syntax is incorrect. The `echo "<h4>OK</h4>";` statement should be within the PHP tags.

Comment: please take a look i improved question

Comment: i need to pass this if(($point < '999') || ($flag == '0') ){ otherwise want to return OK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (!$flag && $point < 1000)
{
    echo "Not OK";
} else {
    echo "OK";
}
```

**Writing this into a truth-table:**

```
flag        point       result
0           < 1000      Not OK
1           < 1000      OK
0           >=1000      OK
1           >=1000      OK
```

Worked for me now as per my question

i think we are all here for some contribution reason, flagging down a question is not a way, if you got solution than respond otherwise my question was 100% clear.

Comment: answered by ccKep [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41997833/use-or-within-if-else-condition-by-inverse-condition-order-in-php/41999855#41999855]

Answer (score 0):

I sincerely don't understand what you're trying to do...

First, if you print nothing, really do print nothing. No need for if/else, a simple if is enough.

```
   <?php
   $point = 1000;
   $points = 1;

   if (($point < 1000) || ($point == 0)) {
       echo '<h4>OK</h4>';
   }
```

This code tests if :

- $points is inferior to 1000
- OR $point is equal to 0

If any of those conditions, or both, returns true, then it prints "OK".

Comment: please take a look i improved question   
i need to pass this if(($point < '999') || ($flag == '0') ){ otherwise want to return OK

Comment: So just invert the conditions, and change it for `$point >= 1000 || $flag != 0`... If you really need to print "not ok", then do it in the else.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you don't need parentheses at all. You could just do this:

```
if($point < 1000 || $whatever == "bar") {
```

Comment: $user_id = $_SESSION['user_id'];
$whatever = "select m_boost from users where id = $user_id ";