# Use OR within if else condition by inverse condition order in php

Tags: php

I am trying to get "OK" if my condition False, i want to keep same if else order as given example, don't advice to move "else" content in "if" and "if" content in "else",

```
 <?php

    //Case 1 Both False
    //$point = 1001; //more than 100
    //$flag  = 1;   //flag is = 0 

    //Case 2 First False Second True
    //$point = 1000; //less than 1000
    //$flag  = 0;   //flag is = 0 

    //Case 3 First TRUE Second FALSE
    //$point = 100; //less than 100
    //$flag  = 1;   //flag is = 1 

    $point = 1001;
    $flag  = 1;   
    ?>

    <div class="box border">
    <div class="box-title">
    <?php if($flag == 0 || $point < 1000) { ?>
    <h4>Not OK</h4>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <h4>OK</h4>
    <?php }?>
    </div>
```

in above script
//Case 1 is working 
but
Case 2 and Case 3 both not working with OR operator

I want all 3 cases work in same pattern

Comment: Possible duplicate of [use OR in if codition to print reverse results in php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41994806/use-or-in-if-codition-to-print-reverse-results-in-php)

Comment: @tkausl, it's not exact same there i were used different example than this question, now my example is pretty clear with testing material, i hope i learn from here

Comment: You want these all three cases to work with output OK right ?

Comment: @rahul_m, right

Comment: All three cases values of flag and point will be same, you just need that condition right ?

Comment: You just want to invert the condition? What have you tried?

Comment: @ccKep, i have tried case1  $point = 1001;
    $flag  = 1;    which is perfect as per my need and returning " OK " but Case 2 and case 3 not working

Comment: @GoargeGo Maybe the example is different but the solutions are the same and there's 3 answers in your other question to help you learn. This question is a duplicate and should be closed.

Comment: If I get you right you want the `OK` in all three cases?

Comment: @ccKep, you are right i want OK in all 3 cases and want to print ok in else statement

Comment: `if ((!$flag && $point <= 1000) || ($flag && $point > 1000)) {`, which basically means `$flag` controls wether you check `$point` for `<=` or `>` (`$flag = false` means you check for `less than/equal`, `$flag = true` means you check for `greater than`)

Comment: @ccKep, this seems good but $flag is just 0 , 1 please edit solution

Comment: @GoargeGo What do you mean `$flag is just 0, 1` ? I don't use any explicit values... This should already be fine. (`0` evaluates to `false` in php while any other value, including `1`, evaluates to `true`). If your problem is that you can't write `== 0` or `== 1` then I can't really help you.

Comment: @ccKep, you almost made :) The above solution is working for Case 2 and Case 3 but stop working on Case 1, now in only case 1 not working

Comment: @ccKep, post this solution as answer in my question so i consider to accept and share to world, i already lost -12 points and post almost 3 question on same topic and now you the only who made it Cheers !

Comment: @ccKep, $flag is variable here and i have declared it as value 1 in example above,

Comment: @ccKep, sure take your time, please think a bit more now this statement in not working for case 1 while working in both Cases 2 & 3, we are only 1 step away from success

Comment: Your case 1 and case 3 contradict themselves, case 1: `flag = 1, point > 1000` should return `true` while case 2: `flag = 1, point <= 1000` should also return `true`. Which means `$flag` has no meaning whatsoever.

Comment: @ccKep, do you know any solution for case 1?

Comment: @GoargeGo If case 1 and case 3 need to be true then there's no need for any check since checking for those would always return true... (a number can't be `>1000` and `<=1000` at the same time). You should edit your question and elaborate on your needs / the signifcance of `$point` and `$flag` (what do they represent? what do you want to check them for? what's your overall goal). Doing this in the first place would probably have saved you some downvotes aswell.

Comment: $point = "select points from users where id = $user_id ";
$flag = "select m_boost from users where id = $user_id ";

Comment: @ccKep, for case 1 let me explain a bit more, in db user earning coins and flag is what if i want to turn on & off from admin and want to show OK to them if their points are greater than 1000 OR flag = 1 if both or at least one condition is TRUE i want to show them ok

Comment: If you just want to show "OK" when `$point >= 1000` or `$flag == 1` then that's just it... pseudocode: `if ($flag || $point >= 1000) { OK } else { Not OK }`. Inversing that so that `Not OK` is in the if just means you need to inverse the condition, basic boolean algebra: `if (!$flag &&  $point < 1000) { Not OK } else { OK }`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After reading your comments:

It seems you want to show some score (in the else-branch of an if-then-else) if the user has equal/more than 1000 points **or** you toggle a flag (which basically means "always show points").

Normally you'd be doing that in the if-branch:

```
if ($flag || $point >= 1000)
{
    echo "OK";
} else {
    echo "Not OK";
}
```

Since you want the `Not OK` to be in the if-Branch you need to inverse the condition, doing so means inverting every part of the condition **and the operators aswell**:

- `$flag` becomes `!$flag`
- `$point >= 1000` becomes `$point < 1000`
- `||` becomes `&&`

Result:

```
if (!$flag && $point < 1000)
{
    echo "Not OK";
} else {
    echo "OK";
}
```

Writing this into a truth-table:

```
flag        point       result
0           < 1000      Not OK
1           < 1000      OK
0           >=1000      OK
1           >=1000      OK
```

Comment: Finally i got solution for my logical problem, this solution is working in all 3 cases cheers:)

Answer (score 0):

I tested this code and it works.

```
if(!($flag != 0 || $point >= 1000)){
    echo "Not OK";
}else{
    echo "OK";
}
```

Comment: please i want inverse condition and want to print " OK " in else statement already mentioned in question